# Rails 6.1.4 - assets:precompile doesn't work because Sprockets::FileNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, assets, sprockets

I begin to work on a new project Rails (v.6.1.4). I clone the repo, bundle install, yarn install but when I try to launch assets:precompile it doesn't work.

I have that message :

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'i18n.js' with type 'application/javascript'
Checked in these paths: 
  /Users/me/code/my-project/app/assets/config
  /Users/me/code/my-project/app/assets/fonts
  /Users/me/code/my-project/app/assets/images
  /Users/me/code/my-project/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/me/code/my-project/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/me/code/my-project/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/me/code/my-project/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/graphiql-rails-1.9.0/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/graphiql-rails-1.9.0/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cloudinary-1.26.0/vendor/assets/html
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cloudinary-1.26.0/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sweetalert-rails-1.1.3/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sweetalert-rails-1.1.3/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/tether-rails-1.4.0/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/tether-rails-1.4.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/momentjs-rails-2.29.4.1/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jquery-minicolors-rails-2.2.6.2/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jquery-minicolors-rails-2.2.6.2/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jquery-rails-4.6.0/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/datetime_picker_rails-0.0.7/app/assets/fonts
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/datetime_picker_rails-0.0.7/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/datetime_picker_rails-0.0.7/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoon-1.2.15/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/js-routes-1.4.14/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/highcharts-rails-6.0.3/app/assets/images
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/highcharts-rails-6.0.3/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/highcharts-rails-6.0.3/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/chart-js-rails-0.1.7/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/chartkick-5.0.2/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/slash_admin-1.5.11/app/assets/config
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/slash_admin-1.5.11/app/assets/images
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/slash_admin-1.5.11/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/slash_admin-1.5.11/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/slash_admin-1.5.11/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/slash_admin-1.5.11/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/actioncable-6.1.4/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activestorage-6.1.4/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/actionview-6.1.4/lib/assets/compiled
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/turbolinks-source-5.2.0/lib/assets/javascripts
  /Users/me/code/my-project/vendor/assets/images/fonts
  /Users/me/code/my-project/node_modules
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pagy-4.11.0/lib/javascripts
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pagy-4.11.0/lib/javascripts
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/popper_js-1.16.1/assets/javascripts
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootstrap-4.4.1/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootstrap-4.4.1/assets/javascripts
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/font-awesome-sass-6.2.1/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/font-awesome-sass-6.2.1/assets/fonts

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I tried everything, by exemple modify Sprockets version or delete the javascript assets, but I have still that line.

Anyone have this problem ? Or a solution ? I can't work since I compile my assets.

Comment: Can you share the repo link? Do you run this to production? Try run precompile like this => `WEBPACKER_PRECOMPILE=false rails assets:precompile`